# jQuery .scrollLeft() not matching as I type in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, scroll, contenteditable

**EDIT**
In the comments, someone pointed out a lack of clarification. I am building a text editor. I initially used a contenteditable div that contained all the text, but realized that if I wanted it to change the text color for special keywords as a programming editor does, I needed to use a better system because after about 30-50 lines it would slowly change the text color. I could have stuck with the previously mentioned idea and made it work (better), but I didn't and switched to an idea of splitting each line up. I currently split every line up as a new contenteditable div, and every line lives within a parent div. Obviously this is complicated, but I achieved it and got all the custom key functions to correctly do what they originally did, such as moving up, down, left, and right with the key arrows, allow text to be appended and removed, and hotkeys are even implemented. In the process I ran into the issue that each line does not allow the horizontal scroll to follow where you are currently typed. The example listed below encapsulates my issue without explaining too much. I really just need an answer to what's below and from there I believe I can make a consensus to use the answer(s) or textwrap the line and figure out an adjustment solution to my line numbering.

---

Initial Question:

I have a very particular case of using an editable div. In my case I have a contenteditable div that on `.keydown()` prevents the default and I add a span with the character that's being typed.

Exp:

```js
function captureKeys() {
  // Let's focus on div
  $("#editable-div").focus();
  
  $("#editable-div").on('keydown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // to stop the normal behavior **ISSUE**

      var span = $(document.createElement('span')); 
      span.text(event.key);

      $(this).append(span);
  });
}
  
$(document).ready( captureKeys );
```

```css
/* Need to stop the text wrap for the editable-div */
#editable-div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <body>
    <div id="editable-div" contenteditable=true>
      <!-- This is where it dynamically puts in strings -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now this is a crude example, not as refinded as my case, but it gets the point across. As you type, the div will not follow where you currently are typing. In fact, you don't move at all because the default behavior is prevented, meaning it needs to be written in. This is because of the `event.preventDefault();` in the key down function.

I am looking **specifically** for solutions to adjusting the `scrollLeft()` without the default behavior of the arrow keys! I wrote in custom functions for the arrow-keys, so the default behavior is not an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// This is not what I want
function captureKeys() {
  // Let's focus on div
  $("#editable-div").focus();
  
  $("#editable-div").on('keydown', function(event) {
      if ([37,38,39,40].includes(event.keyCode)) { 
        // Allowing the default behavior
      } else {
        event.preventDefault(); // to stop the normal behavior of everything but arrow-keys
 
        var span = $(document.createElement('span')); 
        span.text(event.key);

        $(this).append(span);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan sorry, I posted it on accident before finishing the whole question.

Comment: On mobile, when I type in I only get bunch of undefined. Is that OK? Just out of curiosity, what are you building actually?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Picky, aren't we? Sorry for the syntax, but it should've still worked. I'm building a text editor, but with my own custom functions for the key inputs. I'll check the error on my phone as well and see. ~Edit~ I opened this post on my Safari and it did not show the code snippet as something I could run on my phone. I would just run it on a desktop if you'd like to test and post a solution.

Comment: Text editor? Sorry but I don't understand what *text editor* that inserts `"ArrowRight"` and what's the purpose of it - or if that's also an undesired behavior. It's not clear from your question. In a text editor I'm able to caret around and insert text. Your example only **appends** text. Regarding the current state - all you need is to [Element.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) the far right, which pixels amount can be easily retrieved by using the element's `scrollWidth` and that's it. But hat's your least problem here. I hesitate to even answer

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I asked a specific question, and if you do not have an answer that's okay. I won't post my code because the actual code has nothing to do with the issue. I don't plan on posting all my code, but I can explain more if needed.